Considering a limit on subsequences of reals, instead of all reals

Let $f:(0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function satisfying
$$
\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^k}=a \in \overline{\mathbb{R}}, \quad k \in \mathbb{N}^* \backslash\{1\}
$$
and
$$
\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x+1)-f(x)}{x^{k-1}}=b \in \overline{\mathbb{R}}
$$
Prove that $b=k a$.


I have found the following Solution given in the book.

Our assumption implies $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} f(n+1)-f(n) / n^{k-1}=b$. Define $u_n=f(n)$ and $v_n=n^k$. Hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{u_{n+1}-u_n}{v_{n+1}-v_n} & =\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{u_{n+1}-u_n}{n^{k-1}} \cdot \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^{k-1}}{v_{n+1}-v_n} \\
& =\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(n+1)-f(n)}{n^{k-1}} \cdot \frac{n^{k-1}}{(n+1)^k-n^k}=\frac{a}{k}
\end{aligned}
$$
On the other hand, by the Stolz-Cesáro lemma,
$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(n+1)-f(n)}{(n+1)^k-n^k}=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} f(n) n^k
$$
Combining these relations, we deduce that $b=ka$.


My doubt: In the original problem they have given the limit on $x$ which ranges over all reals, however in the solution they have considered limit over a specific real subsequence, more specifically the integers, and concluded results based on that, which doesn't seem justified to me. I do get that both $x$, and $n$ tends to infinity, but in the solution they still consider a specific subsequence of reals, and not all subsequences.
For example in the following function defined from real to real, $f(x)= x \sin(1/x)$, and consider $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ and then look at the limit on the following subsequence: $a_n =n \pi$ which goes to $\infty$ and $n$ goes to $\infty$ then limit is $0$, which is clearly not the case.

A limit of the form $\lim_{x\to \infty}$ implies that the limit exists along any real sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_n\to \infty$, and the value of the limit is independent of the choice of sequence. In your example the limit $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$ does not exist for precisely the reason you give.
